# calculate all possible combinations with respect to a conditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, examples-counterexamples

---

we have a group of people 5 men and 7 womens
we take 2 men and 3 womens to form a group
how many possible groups we can have if 2 women can't be in the same group?

the 2 women can be any womens from the  7 womens

Comment: Let number of women = $w$, men = $m$, are you saying that in a group $w \neq 2$ or that $w \leq 1$?

Comment: 2 womens like may a and b can't be in the same group so we have to rmove them

Comment: You cannot select three women if *any* two women can't be in the same group.  They would have to be two *particular* women.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many ways can you select $2$ from $5$ men, $2$ from $5$ women, and $1$ from those $2$ specified women?

How many ways can you select $2$ from $5$ men, $3$ from $5$ women, and $0$ from those $2$ specified women?

Add the result.